# UIDatePicker swift save time

Tags: ios, swift, time, uidatepicker

I am trying to save the selected time of some UIDatePickers that I have. My date picker is called datePicker1. It is currently set to just hour and minute I have a "save" button and I want to save the datePickers time (hour and minute) and be able to call back those times later on. I am currently using NSUserDefaults but if there is a better way to do this, let me know. (The date has nothing to do with it, I am creating an app that will give the user a notification every day so all I care about is the hour and minute count). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't specify in what format you want to save the time (e.g. a string?  integers for hour and minute?  a NSDate object?)

Comment: So what you want exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

In the event you want to save the hours and minutes as a string, this might give you some ideas. This implementation involves an outlet to a single UIDatePicker and an action attached to a "Save" button:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func save(sender: UIButton) {

    let dateOnPicker = datePicker.date //capture the date shown on the picker

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter() //create a date formatter

    //if you want to convert time to string like "9:07 PM":
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle //check out docs for NSDateFormatterStyle to see other styles
    let timeAsString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateOnPicker)
    print(timeAsString) //ex. prints 3:04 AM as "3:04 AM" and 11:37 PM as "11:37 PM"

    //if you want to convert time to string like "0627" (military time):
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm" //could also store as HH:mm if you want a colon in the string 
    let timeAsStringMilitaryTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateOnPicker)
    print(timeAsStringMilitaryTime) //in miliatary time: ex. prints 3:04AM as "0304" and 11:37 PM as "2337"

    //there are other options, but these are two that you might find useful!

    //you could then save either version (whichever you end up using) to NSUserDefaults as a string; i went with the military time version since i think it's easier to parse, but just personal preference:
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(timeAsStringMilitaryTime, forKey: "SavedTime")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //when you start up (or whenever you want to retrieve the saved time), you could check to see if you have a time saved, and if so, parse it into hours and minutes (assuming you are saving the military time version):

    if let savedTime = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SavedTime") as? String {

        //the "HHmm" military time format will ALWAYS be 4 digits long, and the first two characters represent the hours and the second two characters represent the minutes

        let hoursRange = savedTime.startIndex...savedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(1)  //refers to the first two digits of 4-digit time)
        let hours =  savedTime[hoursRange]

        let minutesRange = savedTime.startIndex.advancedBy(2)...savedTime.endIndex.predecessor()  //refers to the last two digits of 4-digit time)
        let minutes = savedTime[minutesRange]

        print(hours)
        print(minutes)
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is helpful!

Mike

Comment: Mike, so I get how to save the time, now if I want to use that time to trigger an alert, and when that page is reloaded, the date picker shows the saved time again, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIDatePickerView: (set to Time in the storyboard)
The following functions will save/load the time as NSDate and since your UIDatePickerView is set to Time, only hours / minutes will be displayed

Define a variable "time" where you save your selected date

```
var date :NSDate?
```

Use this function to save data to variable

```
func save(){
    date = datePicker1.date
}
```

Use this function to load data from variable

```
func load(){
    if date != nil {
        datePicker1.setDate(date!, animated: true)
    }
}
```